# Openning a port with ZTE Router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

Can you tell me if i am doing something wrong trying to opening a port? This is driving me crazy. I have a desktop computer (192.168.1.64 internal ip adress) connected to internet via modem/router (ZTE H108N) (192.168.1.1). I enter to router configuration typing 192.168.1.1 in a browser and accessing with "admin" user. Ok, then I go to "Advance" -> "Port forwarding"

Click on "Add" and fill the next form:

So, I select the next data:

- WAN Connections: PVC: 8/36  (don't know what this means)
- Custom Server: JBOSS
- Schedule: Always
- Server IP Address(Host Name): 192.168.1.64

First line of the table (i don't know why there are other 11 records):
 - External Port Start: 8080
 - External Port End: 8080
 - Protocol: TCP
 - Internal Port Start: 8080
 - Internal Port End: 8080
 - Remote Ip: Empty

When I click on "Add" a new record on the table is showed. Then I go to this website https://www.whatismyip.com/es/ to know my "public" adress. After, go to this other site "http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/" to test my port but it is always closed :S.

Before do the test:

- Firewall on windows is disabled
- Firewall on router is disabled
- Antivirus is disabled
- Application running on the port listening (Jboss - 8080)

Is there something i am missing?? The manual is not very useful either "Google: Manual-usuario-fabricante-Home-Station-ZTE-H108N.pdf"

Best Regards!

P.D. I could not post the images because i have no reputation. But you can see the same question in this forum ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981229/openning-a-port") before i have to delete it.

Comment: "Remote Ip: Empty" it should be 192.168.1.64

Comment: I am not at home right know but i will test that. In that case, what is the difference with  field "Server IP Address(Host Name)"?

Comment: [How to open a port on the ZTE ZXHN H108N](https://portforward.com/zte/zxhn-h108n/)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I have already seen that link but it is not the same version apparently.